# C# What object or design would one use to create an interactive distance chart

Tags: c#, charts

What object would one use to display cities running on the side and top of a chart, where the distance of the aligned cites will be displayed. 
I want something interactive where one could click on the distance "cell" one will get more information on that specific distance.

In summary what object should I use to display the cities on the top and side of the chart?

Thank in advance

Comment: I would use a datagridview. I am wondering if there is documentation on how to implement a distance chart

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I did in the end to solve the problem:

I used a datagridview! Using a List populated by city name form the cities table, I named the header of the column and row of the Datagridview.
Then I used the count of the table to define the matrix `Distance[List<>.count, List<>.count]`
Then I used a nested for loop to populated the datagrid.